# Can I cap one of my plumbing vents?

Tags: plumbing

my concrete slab was just poured for my new house. One of the plumbing vents (2 inch) that vents the master shower was put in the wrong place. The wall it is supposed to increase into the attic to vent needs to be around at least 8-10 inches further.

Can this vent be cut evenly with the slab and capped? My buddy and I put in the underground plumbing so we didn’t have a licensed contractor do the job. My buddy made a mistake on the measurement. What is the best solution? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your drain will probably not work properly if you cap it. Is it possible to place a cabinet or something over that spot and run it over the floor, under the cabinet until you get to the wall?

Comment: If your jurisdiction allows AAV’s this may be a possibility but never cut any pipe at the slab , / several inches above could save hundreds if not thousands , have fixed 1/2 dozen jobs where they thought they were wrong and cutt it off only to have to expose the pipe below the slab and then seal with hydraulic cement.

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not possible. The vent is where our tiled walk in shower will be. I fear my only option may be cutting the concrete and moving it 

Comment: Or maybe changing the layout of your bathroom ?

Comment: do not do it, it needs the vent

Comment: if you have access to the vent pipe reroute it

Answer (score 4):

"concrete just poured" - so it's fresh, green, and weak as heck. Get in there as soon as possible (it's getting stronger while you wait) and chop out what you need to chop out while it's still easy, and redirect the vent to where it needs to be, then pour a patch.

Same thing you'd do anyway, just **much** easier while the concrete is green, fresh, weak.

Answer (score 0):

your best solution is to fit a connector and redirect the vent where you want it to be.

You may have to raise the floor level of your shower, or cut a groove in the concrete to acommodate this relocation.

fortunately the rules for vent pipes are more lenient when it comes to adding bends than they are for drain pipes.

10" doesn't seem too bad. an angle grinder with a few stone cutting wheels should manage that, or you could hire a concrete saw (which is probably the easier way).